# How to create salesforce validation for time using REGEX?

Tags: regex, validation, salesforce

I'm trying to build a sort of punch-card/scheduling system in Salesforce. I've gotten as far as getting a "visual workflow" to create multiple records using a single input screen.

I now need to make it idiot proof by adding a REGEX validation rule forcing the time to be entered in a single format  **(HH:MM am/pm)** .

I found this piece of REGEX for SLQ

```
((([0]?[1-9]|1[0-2])(:|\.)[0-5][0-9]((:|\.)[0-5][0-9])?( )?(AM|am|aM|Am|PM|pm|pM|Pm))|(([0]?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(:|\.)[0-5][0-9]((:|\.)[0-5][0-9])?))
```

(I removed the ^ at the beginning and the $ at the end)

But when entering it in Salseforce I got an error

> The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Found '['.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. (Sorry if this ran a little long)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex posted there is intended to handle many different formats of time.  It seems like your goal is to be a little less flexible, so perhaps a better regex for you would be something simpler like

```
[0-1]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9] [A|P]M"
```

This would allow times like

09:08 PM

12:49 AM

1:32 PM

but would disallow things like

23:42

23:42 PM

1:09 pm

In general with regex it's best to start with something simple like this and then expand on it.

Now, because you want to use this in a validation rule, you have to remember that you want this rule to fire when the regex *doesn't* match (because that's when you want to throw an error, when somebody has input an invalid time format).  So your rule will actually look like

```
NOT(REGEX( Time__c , "[0-1]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9] [A|P]M"))
```

Comment: This would still allow invalid times like "15:30 PM". To fix that use something like `(0?[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] [A|P]M`.

Comment: @AndersJohansson I tried your formula and Salesforce had trouble with it.